# use react-jsonschema-form field events

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I have a simple schema to generate form.I want to do some actions on the fields when mouse over occur. but I don't know how can I add mouse over to all fields. By reading the [Documents](http://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#react-jsonschema-form) I found that there are some events for form fields. 
 - Form field blur events
 - Form field focus events
There isn't any example for them although. Please help me to understand where can I set the mouse over event? 
This is my schema:

```
 "schema":
         {
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "request": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "requester": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "requestDate": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "detailList": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "id": "urn:jsonschema:com:fanap:demo:entity:ItemRequestDetail",
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "item": {
                                        "id": "urn:jsonschema:com:fanap:demo:entity:ItemClass",
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "name": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "requestedAmount": {
                                        "type": "number"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "state": {
                            "id": "urn:jsonschema:com:fanap:demo:entity:CategoryElement",
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                "processResult": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "notificationMessage": { "type": "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

and this is my component for showing generated form:

```
class JsonFormWrapper extends React.Component<PropsT> {
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.jsonResponse ? (
                <Form
                    schema={this.props.jsonResponse.schema}
                    uiSchema={this.props.jsonResponse.uiSchema}
                />
            ) : null}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
 }
 export default JsonFormWrapper;
```

how can I set mouse over for all the elements?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do on mouse over event?

Comment: I think it is not important but I want to show some control buttons on top of each element that get mouse over.

Comment: I don't think they provide on mouse over event functionality. You can create a custom widget and add the mouse over event to that widget. If you want a code snippet for that, I can help you

Comment: you have good solution but I have several component that jsonSchema has it by default. for example I have checkbox , textarea, text, fieldset , .... that I want to show control buttons on top of them. as you said I should write custom widget for all of them. do you think it is right? maybe it is better if I add this event to all react-jsonSchema existing widget and then use it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a hacky solution but you can utilize [Field Template](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#field-template) to define custom events like on mouse over. If that works, you will have to define it once and not repeat it for every input field